# C Function to return char gives conflicting types error

Tags: c, function, memory, compiler-errors

I'm new to C and wrote the following code that returns a char.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
   char c = test();
   printf("num = %c \n", c);
}

char test(){
   char c = 'z';
   return c;
}
```

But I get the following error when compiling:

```
read.c:8:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
 test();
 ^
read.c:71:6: error: conflicting types for ‘test’
 char test(){
      ^
read.c:8:1: note: previous declaration of ‘test’ was here
 test();
 ^
```

Any ideas? Does this require memory allocation? If so, why?

Comment: Always put your main(...) function at the bottom of the C file., otherwise you need to add function prototypes at the top of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you either have to define the function prototype above the main, or move the function above the main.

```
char test();

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
   char c = test();
   printf("num = %c \n", c);
}

char test(){
   char c = 'z';
   return c;
}
```

or

```
char test(){
   char c = 'z';
   return c;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
   char c = test();
   printf("num = %c \n", c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `test` before it's declared. Either declare it before the `main` function, or provide its prototype:

```
/* Prototype of test */
char test();

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
   char c = test();
   printf("num = %c \n", c);
}

char test() {
   char c = 'z';
   return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a prototype for `test()` function by the time you call it in `main()`. Either do `char test(void);` at the top of your source file (or more conventionally in a header file).

Other option is to move the definition of `test()` *above* `main()` function which would the ensure the definition itself provides the prototype.

The reason for the error:

```
 error: conflicting types for ‘test’
```

is that in pre-C99 C, compiler implicitly provides an `int` returning prototype for `test()` (known as *implicit int rule*) which conflicts with the actual definition of `test()` (where it actually has `char` as return type). Note that this is no longer valid (in C99 and later).

Answer (score 0):

In C the compiler start "reading" the code from the top to the bottom, so when it's on your main function trying to figure out what is test() it don't know this function yet.
To solve it you can put your main funcion after the test() function, or use function prototype wich is better code practice, manly for future readings of the code. Like this:

```
char test();

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
   char c = test();
   printf("num = %c \n", c);
}

char test(){
   char c = 'z';
   return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using the name `test` in this statement

```
char c = test();
```

it must be declared.

And this message

```
read.c:8:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
 test();
 ^
```

says that the compiler does not know the type of the expression `test()` used in the declaration of the variable `c` as an initializer.

For compatibility with old versions of the C Standard the compiler assumes that the function has the return type `int`. However then it encounters that the function has the return type `char`. And these compiler messages say about this

```
read.c:71:6: error: conflicting types for ‘test’
 char test(){
      ^
read.c:8:1: note: previous declaration of ‘test’ was here
 test();
 ^
```

So before using the function you have to declare it

```
char test( void );
```

Pay attention to that the parameters of the function `main`

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
```

are not used. So the function `main` could be declared like

```
int main( void ){
```

So the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

char test( void );

int main( void ) 
{
    char c = test();
    printf( "num = %c\n", c );

    return 0;
}

char test( void )
{
    char c = 'z';

    return c;
}
```